# Bootstrap 4 .nav-link padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the padding-left of the first `.nav-link` in `.navbar-nav`.

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3XK7.png).

In bootstrap 4 I created a nav and gave padding to `.nav-link`:

```css
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="navigation container-fluid">
  <nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.flakneconstructionllc.com">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

But it's not working because there is a `.nav-item` between the `.navbar-nav` & `.nav-link`.

Do you guys have any solution?

How can I select first item in this case?

Comment: Can you added a working snippet ?

Comment: I have added HTML, CSS and Tried CSS above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with the `pl-0` padding utility class. You can use it on the first `nav-link`, and on the `navbar` too if you want to remove *all* of the left whitespace.

```
<section class="navigation container-fluid">
    <nav class="container pl-0 navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="http://www.flakneconstructionllc.com">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="gallery">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/hIgX0LyIaB

To use CSS to target the first link use...

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item:first-child .nav-link {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It works. but can I do it using css? do you have any solution?

Comment: Oh. Thanks. That's what I was searching for. But Can we select elements using nth-child if the condition is like above? just for knowledge. :)

Comment: Ok, so for selecting `nth-child`, the link is only a single child, while the nav-item has siblings so `first-child` works. Also, can you edit the question and include the [tag:bootstrap-4] tag?