# Boostrap nav bar does not add spaces between items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I started learning HTML, CSS and bootstrap recently.

I was testing navbars and I am not sure why there are no spaces between the items in the navbar.

Here is the code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Nav Bars </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kofee</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is the screenshot of how it shows to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rogv6.png)

Thanks for your time for helping out.

Comment: The class on the link should be `nav-link`, instead of `nav-item` again. The `nav-link` class has paddings.

Comment: this simliar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805650/bootstrap-4-nav-link-padding

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Nav Bars </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kofee</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

As mentioned by David, `nav-item` does not have padding, but `nav-link` does.

Here is a resource for navbars: [Bootstrap Navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)

Using this resource, I was able to see that the standard is to use `nav-item` for the `<li>` tags and `nav-link` for the `<a>` tags in a navbar.

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect class is added in `<a>` tag
Just replace `nav-item` class with `nav-link` class inside `<a>` tag and it will take care of paddings and margins.
**Changes--**

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
```

Do the same in all `<li>`
**Note:-** Download the zip file from Bootstraps official site and refer to the `css/bootstrap.min.css` file to check the actual code. `nav-item` class do not have any margins or paddings.